# multitouch: pointerIndex out of range

Tags: java, android

I'm having some trouble with handling multi-touch in android game:
when I touch the screen with three or more fingers, remove them, and touch it again I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range, which occurs in this line of code in onTouchEvent :     x = (int) event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(a));
```

Here is the code

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    //touch positions
    int x, y;
    //number of touched areas
    int num = event.getPointerCount();
    //masked touch action
    int action = event.getActionMasked();

    if(1 < num && num < 3)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < num; a++)
        {
            x = (int) event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(a));
            y = (int) event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(a));
            switch (action)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case  MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    if(y > screenY/2)  point1.set(x, y);
                    if(y < screenY/2)  point2.set(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();
        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case  MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                if(y > screenY/2)  point1.set(x, y);
                if(y < screenY/2)  point2.set(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: does `findPointerIndex()` return -1?

Comment: i'm not sure, how can I find it out?

Comment: by using `Log.d()` method and watchimg the `logcat` window

Comment: when i tap two fingers it returns 1, when three it returns 2 and crushes

Comment: oh, now i noticed it has returned -1 just before crushing

Comment: the docs say: *"Returns either the index of the pointer (for use with getX(int) et al.), or -1 if there is no data available for that pointer identifier."*

Comment: so how can I prevent that?

Comment: and for what `action` does it happen? use `actionToString` static method for logging purposes

Comment: removing 3 or more fingers from the touch screen at once

Comment: use `MotionEvent.actionToString` in `Log.d`

Comment: returnig: ACTION_MOVE
06-14 11:09:39.053 11430-11430/com.example.mateuszfijak.pongz D/pointer: returnig: -1
    returnig: ACTION_DOWN
06-14 11:09:39.053 11430-11430/com.example.mateuszfijak.pongz E/MotionEvent-JNI: An exception occurred: pointerCount 2, pointerIndex -1.
06-14 11:09:39.055 11430-11430/com.example.mateuszfijak.pongz E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range

Comment: move both paddles at once

Comment: aha i see it now... but you would need `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` as well...

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, actually i added try/catch block and it is working now

Comment: actually you can pass `a` to `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` methods - no need for `findPointerIndex` - it should be in range [0 .. getPointerCount()-1] - so for two fingers you can pass 0 and 1, for three fingers 0, 1 and 2

Comment: and of course no need for `if(1 < num && num < 3)` and `else`  - just do it in one loop

Comment: thats right, thanks!